# How to get apache and mysql error logs via php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, error-log

I have been working on PHP. i have a doubt how to get `apache and mysql error logs` path using php. 
For php error log we can go for `ini_get("error_log")`. is there any way like above for apache and mysql error logs ? we can get mysql path using following query `show variables like '%log%'` but it is not accessible . can i access mysql/apache error logs in shared hosting ?

Comment: I don't know about Apache since it's the server itself (it's more likely to get errors from PHP in Apache logs, if it's running as module), but you can get MySQL errors if you're using [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) functions or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files